# How can i resolve to a Unicode font with Qt?

Tags: qt, unicode, fonts, pdf-generation

I have a Qt 4.8 Application using QGraphicsScene under Windows XP.

If i select the Font "Arial" for a QGraphicsTextItem Object i can use it to display Chinese, Japanese etc.
When i export my Document using Qts PDF Engine:

```
QPrinter *sPDFPrinter = new QPrinter;
sPDFPrinter->setOutputFormat (QPrinter::PdfFormat);
```

The Pdf Correctly embedds the unicode version of "Arial", named "ArialUnicodeMSStandard".

How is this resolving done? I want to use it for other exports as well.

Comment: Uhm, if it embeds Arial Unicode MS then it's doing something very wrong, actually. That's not the font you asked for and no such font linking exists on Windows by default. Heck, Arial Unicode MS is horribly outdated, has a plethora of bugs and is only intended as a fallback font (and it's an Office font, not a Windows font).

Comment: Which font should be used instead of ArialUnicodeMSStandard? The normal "Arial" font does not contain all characters.

Comment: There will never be a font that contains all possible characters. Usually you use different fonts for different scripts that go well together. Windows has font linking for that, so you get a similar style for CJK glyphs as the base font, even though Arial, Times and others contain no such glyphs.

Comment: So i have now 2 Questions instead of one: 1)What fondt should be embedded instead of "Arial"; 2) How can i do the font mapping?

Comment: Arial should be ok; and the mapping should ideally be done by whatever is outputting the text, in your case Qt or Windows.

Comment: But how can i resolve the font? Somewhere Qt silently replaces "Arial" by "ArialUnicodeMSStandard". How can i do that myself?